# C# RestSharp: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel error

Tags: rest, ssl, restsharp

I am using RestSharp v106.15.0; block of code as follows:

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true; 
    RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
    RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest($"{this.BaseURL}");
    restRequest.AddJsonBody(payload);
    IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Post(restRequest);
```

I get "0" for a status code and restResponse.ErrorMessage alternates between the following two message:

- The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
- The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I can however successfully POST to the same API endpoint in Postman without issue. I also have this same code working in several other environments without issue; so I am thinking it is an issue with this one customer's environment, just don't know where else to look. I am also working with Net Framework 4.8 installed.

I also tried variations of code found on SO posted with similar error messages; but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

So I wanted to follow back up on this in case it will be of help to anyone else encountering this problem. As I mentioned, I tried everything I could find, but nothing seemed to apply to my situation.

I did find a great reference though that ultimately led me to my solution: https://blog.jonschneider.com/2016/08/fix-ssl-handshaking-error-in-windows.html

While the resolution referenced above did not work for me, it did make me take notice that this could possibly be a Windows OS issue. I had noted that the server my software was having an issue with was running Windows Server 2012 Standard. I went back to a handful of other servers that have been running my software for years and noted none were running OS versions older than Windows Server 2016.

So I went back to my customer who had an extra VM running Windows Server 2016. I installed everything there and the problem went away! Now, I will admit I don't know why exactly why this worked, but since I had already spent days researching this issue, I decided to thank the IT gods and take the win. :-)